# Here Maps on Live tile(flip tile) windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, here-api

I want to put here map on tile, is it possible? I am using flip tile?

I want to put map current location on flip tile (back part).

Comment: You need to render it using `WriteableBitmap`, have you tried searching on "how to create custom live tile?"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, on this site we like to see that people already put some effort in trying to solve their own question.

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments you would need to use the WriteableBitmap to get the map written to an image. And for that task there is example available Windows Phone 8 Examples: [Maps Samples at Github](http://github.com/nokia-developer/maps-samples)

So you could start by looking into the SaveMapImageEx example in there.